# Уменьшение png файлов

Tags: php

Возникла следующая проблема, при работе с изображениями: не уменьшаются и не сохраняются изображения в формате png, причем jpeg файлы уменьшаются и сохраняются нормально. Пробовал принудительно изменять в названии файла расширение на jpeg - не помогло, картинки всю равно не хотят сохраняться и уменьшаться. Может быть, кто-нибудь сталкивался с этой проблемой?

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible) 
JPG Support     enabled
PNG Support     enabled
```

Сам обработчик следующий:

```
# путь и имя файла оригинальной картинки
    $source_src = 'путь до картинки'; 
    # считываем параметры (высота/ширина, тип и т.п.)
    # оригинальной картинки
    $params = getimagesize($source_src);
    # в зависимости от типа оригинальной картинки
    # применяем соответствующую функцию для считывания
    # и создания изображения с которым будем работать

    $format = strtolower(substr($params['mime'], strpos($params['mime'], '/')+1));
    $icfunc = "imagecreatefrom" . $format;

    $source = $icfunc($source_src);

    # максимально допустимый размер
    # (по ширине/высоте) уменьшенной картинки
    $max_size = 190;
    # если ширина или высота оригинальной картинки
    # больше ограничения производим вычисления
    if ( $params[0]>$max_size || $params[1]>$max_size ) 
        {
        # выбираем большее: ширины или высота
        # оригинальной картинки
        if ( $params[0]>$params[1] ) $size = $params[0]; # ширина
            else $size = $params[1]; # высота
        # используя нехитрую пропорцию вычислям
        # ширину и высоту уменьшенной картинки

        $nsize=getNewSize('путь до картинки',190,300);

        $resource_width = $nsize['w'];
        $resource_height = $nsize['h'];

        $resource = imagecreatetruecolor($resource_width, $resource_height); // создание «подкладки»

        # изменение размера и копирование полученного на «подкладку»
        imagecopyresampled($resource, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nsize['w'], $nsize['h'], $params[0], $params[1]);
        }
        # если изменять размер не надо просто присваиваем переменной
        # $resource идентификатор оригинальной картинки
            else $resource = $source;

    //$end = end(explode('.', $picurl));
    $end = 'jpeg';

    imagejpeg($resource, 'название новой картинки'.'.$end, 100);
    imagedestroy($resource);
```

Скрипт взял из паблика, джипеги обрабатывает нормально, но png почему то не хочет...

Comment: Возможно, криво собран PHP или библиотека GD или ImageMagick, или какая у вас используется для обработки изображений?

Что в логах ошибок?

Comment: В логах вроде как ошибок.
Поправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Никогда не понимал зачем для создания thumb'ов писать столько кода, когда это можно сделать одной строчкой:

```
exec("convert sourceImage.jpg -thumbnail '190x300^' output.png");
```

Или так:

```
$image = new Imagick('sourceImage.jpg');
$image->thumbnailImage(190, 300, true);
$image->writeImage('output.png');
```

Хотя первый способ предпочтительнее.

PS

> Криво собран php, проблема с GD - facenapalm...

Теоретически, GD можно собрать без поддержки png.

Comment: Далеко не каждом шаред хостинге exec разрешен, а превьюшки делать нужно. Я сам не сталкивался никогда, чтобы GD так был собран без png, но думаю если бы не было поддержки png при запуске imagecreatefrompng ругнулся бы в лог, а со слов ТС-а, лог без ошибок. Ну и плюс PNG Support enabled какбэ намекает что всё ок :)

Comment: @Зоркий ну так столкнитесь: я имел дело с ситуацией, когда на хостинге при сборке своей версии PHP не подключалась поддержка PNG из стандартных библиотек хостинга `--with-png-dir=... --with-jpeg-dir=...`

`PNG Support enabled` ТС добавил после моего уточнения.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в предпоследней строчке, в функции `imagejpeg`.
В скрипте есть проверка:

```
$icfunc = "imagecreatefrom" . $format;
```

т.е. для `png` файла будет вызвана функция `imagecreatefrompng()`, но сохранять `png` нужно функцией `imagepng()`, а не `imagejpeg()`. Сохранять этот файл также нужно как `*.png`, а не `*.jpeg`.

Криво собран `php`, проблема с `GD - facenapalm`...

Comment: Может там как Facebook — уменьшая GIF, PNG — из всех форматов создаёт JPEG?